# Advent of AV.SE, are questions about DAW related software issues welcomed?

Tags: discussion

Are questions surrounding ProTools, Abelton, Kommand 8, and like software relevant?  I don't mean, "How do you EQ in PT", but more along the lines of, "I can do X with one user but not another on the same system"?  Does this make sense?

Answer (score 3):

In general, if it runs on a PC or other system within the scope of the FAQ
, its still alright here. Its the same arguement we have about platform/vendor specific sites such as AU - We'd prefer people ask it on the site they feel is the best fit (ie please don't crosspost), but it'll get moved if you asked nicely. We don't mind such questions though.